# Error al pasar unos test por no contar con valores null/undefined(?)

Tags: java

Basicamente estoy haciendo un reto de codewars pero me dice que cuente con valores null/undefined. ¿No se supone que el codigo tal cual esta resolveria que cuente cuantos true hay en la lista? La idea es que haga esto: >Consider an array/list of sheep where some sheep may be missing from their place. We need a function that counts the number of sheep present in the array (true means present).

```
public class Counter {
  public int countSheeps(Boolean[] arrayOfSheeps) {
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfSheeps.length; i++){
      if(arrayOfSheeps[i] == true) cont++;
    }
    return cont;
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: como hago para que cuente con que la lista que recibe como parametro la funcion contenga null o undefined

Comment: Si el array en si mismo es null, qué crees que va a pasar cuando hagas `null.lenght` en tu bucle??

Comment: Supongo que una excepcion no?